# CORS not working with Spring Boot and Spring Cloud without Spring Security

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

I am using Spring Boot 2.2.4.RELEASE **with** Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR1 and **without** Spring Security, In that GET method is working fine but POST & PUT methods are not working.

```
@Configuration
@Order(value = Integer.MAX_VALUE)
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:5500")
            .allowedHeaders("*")
            .allowedMethods("POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD");
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

        chain.doFilter(req, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

AngularJS Code

```
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://b28c-103-85-11-107.ngrok.io/game/brand-styles',
        data: {
            "fontColour": "FFFFFF",
            "backgroundColour": "006400",
            "displayType": 1,
            "buttonColour": "FFC314"
            }
        })
        .then(function (response) { $scope.data = data; })
        .catch(function (err) { console.log(err) });
```

[image]

I have tried multiple ways to solve the issue as suggested on same platform in different questions but no one worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://b28c-103-85-11-107.ngrok.io/game/brand-styles' from origin
> 'http://localhost:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.
>
> POST http://b28c-103-85-11-107.ngrok.io/game/brand-styles
> net::ERR_FAILED

The possible reason behind the issue in your case would be due to the following statement that you've mentioned in the `SimpleCORSFilter` class.

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
```

Looks like `Origin` header is dropped before reaching to your local server or may be dropped by the local server itself. You can try with the following change to verify your case.

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:5500");
```